# why does my jquery code pick up more rows than I'm expecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html table:

```
<table id="tbltimeconditions" class="table table-bordered table-hover tcdata">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <h3>Time Conditions&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="enabletc" id="enabletc" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit Time Conditions"></h3>
        <button id="addtc" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle tctamper" style=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </td>
      <!--<td class="tctamper"></td>-->

    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="tc_dirty" name="tc_dirty" value="true">            
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="del_tc1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle deletetcrow"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;TC 1:</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control starttc " type="input" placeholder="UTC Start Time (format 00:00:00)" name="starttime1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="input" placeholder="UTC End Time (format 00:00:00)" name="endtime1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="input" placeholder="Extension" name="extension1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="input" placeholder="Domain" name="domain1">
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><b>Days of Week:</b></label>
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_m1" name="dow_m1">Mon&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_t1" name="dow_t1">Tue&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_w1" name="dow_w1">Wed&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_r1" name="dow_r1">Thu&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_f1" name="dow_f1">Fri&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_s1" name="dow_s1">Sat&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_n1" name="dow_n1">Sun&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="submitbtnsection">
      <td colspan="6" align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" class="btn btn-warning submit" value="Cancel">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" name="unassign" id="unassign" class="btn btn-warning" value="Unassign DID">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the jquery logic I have to find all the rows of data the user has inputted:

```
var rowCount = $('#tbltimeconditions tr').length;
console.log(rowCount + " is the rowCount");
if (rowCount >= 3) {      // 3 because 1 for heading, 1 for '+' button row, 1 row for submit button

        $('.tcdata tr').each(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row);                          
            var $ext = $row.find('input[name*="extension"]');           
 console.log($ext.val() + " is the ext")    ;               
            var $start = $row.find('input[name*="starttime"]');
            var $end = $row.find('input[name*="endtime"]');
            var $domain = $row.find('input[name*="domain"]');

            if ( !$start.val() || !$end.val() || !$domain.val() ) {
                        $(".emessbox").html("Whoops!  Every time condition must have a start / end time, and a domain");                        
                        e.preventDefault();             
                        return;
            }
            //check days of week. 
            var $dow_m = $row.find('input[name*="dow_m"]');
            var $dow_t = $row.find('input[name*="dow_t"]');
            var $dow_w = $row.find('input[name*="dow_w"]');
            var $dow_r = $row.find('input[name*="dow_r"]');
            var $dow_f = $row.find('input[name*="dow_f"]');
            var $dow_s = $row.find('input[name*="dow_s"]');
            var $dow_n = $row.find('input[name*="dow_n"]');
           if ( (!$dow_m[0].checked ) && (! $dow_t[0].checked ) && (!$dow_w[0].checked ) && (!$dow_r[0].checked ) && (!$dow_f[0].checked) && (!$dow_s[0].checked) && (!$dow_n[0].checked) ) {

                if ( /^dow_[mtwrfsn]{1}[0]{1}$/.test($dow_m.attr("name"))== true  ) {

                    $(".emessbox").html("Whoops! Every time condition must have a day of week assign to it");
                    e.preventDefault();             
                    //console.log('abuot to existin here');
                    return;
                }
            }
```

**Problem**

The jquery code that I've written to filter for only the actual rows of data is returning more than I want.  So in the above rendered HTML table example, I only actually have one row of data... but captures all three rows in the table and returns the output:

```
undefined is the ext
8659111 is the ext
undefined is the ext
```

**Question**

I thought that this line:

```
 $('.tcdata tr').each(function (i, row) {
```

would return all rows in my table that has the class "tcdata".
And then I thought that this line:

```
            var $ext = $row.find('input[name*="extension"]');
```

would filter each row and only give me rows that have input controls with names that match the pattern, in this case "extension".

But it's clearly giving me more than I want and so the code is failing. 
I can't seem to find my mistake.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `class` as `tcdata` in required `<tr>` tags and you have to change `$('.tcdata tr').each(function (i, row) {` this to `$('tr.tcdata').each(function (i, row) {`

This way it will return just the rows you required.

**JS**

```
$('tr.tcdata').each(function (i, row) { ... });
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="tcdata">
      <td>
        <button id="del_tc1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle deletetcrow"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;TC 1:</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control starttc " type="input" placeholder="UTC Start Time (format 00:00:00)" name="starttime1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="input" placeholder="UTC End Time (format 00:00:00)" name="endtime1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="input" placeholder="Extension" name="extension1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control " type="input" placeholder="Domain" name="domain1">
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><b>Days of Week:</b></label>
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_m1" name="dow_m1">Mon&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_t1" name="dow_t1">Tue&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_w1" name="dow_w1">Wed&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_r1" name="dow_r1">Thu&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_f1" name="dow_f1">Fri&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_s1" name="dow_s1">Sat&nbsp;
        <input class="checkbox-inline " type="checkbox" id="dow_n1" name="dow_n1">Sun&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var $ext = $row.find('input[name*="extension"]');` will always return something. If there are no results, you'll get back an empty jQuery object whose length is 0. One way to fix your code would be to make sure `$ext.length > 0` before proceeding.